# Have an environment variable that displays current date zsh

Tags: linux, environment-variables, zsh

Is there a way to create an environment variable that displays current date each time it is displayed? I tried

```
CURRDATE="`date "+%H:%M:%S"`"
```

but the value is fixed at creation time:

```
>echo $CURRDATE
23:41:46
>echo $CURRDATE
23:41:46
>echo $CURRDATE
23:41:46
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to create a variable that behaves that way on its own in zsh. The value of variables does not change unless set from the outside.

`CURRDATE` would have to be set to the correct time regularly or at least everytime just before it is needed.

Luckily zsh can help with that. Add this to your `.zshrc`:

```
export CURRDATE
currdate() {
    CURRDATE=$(date "+%H:%M:%S")
}
add-zsh-hook preexec currdate
```

This adds `CURRDATE` to the environment and will update it each time just before a command line is run.

```
% echo $CURRDATE
12:34:56
% echo $CURRDATE
12:34:57
% env | grep CURRDATE
CURRDATE=12:34:58
```

Note that `CURRDATE` will not be updated while the command runs, that is you can only pass the start date but not the entire clock. Also `CURRDATE` is the same for all commands on the same command line:

```
% echo $CURRDATE; sleep 10; echo $CURRDATE
12:34:56
12:34:56
```

Answer (score 2):

`SECONDS` is close to what you want. You can set its value to the current time, and the current shell will continue to increment its value.

```
% SECONDS=$(date +%s)
% echo $SECONDS
1390597152
% echo $SECONDS
1390597153
% echo $SECONDS
1390597154
```

If you want a variable with a custom name, you'll have to arrange for it to be updated inside one of the hook functions.

```
precmd () {
    CURRDATE=$(date +%s)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for solution as:

```
echo $(date "+%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: kind of, except that I need it to be in an environment variable so that it can be retrieved later using getenv()

Comment: In this case it would be better an alias
      alias curdate='echo $(date "+%H:%M:%S")'

Comment: looks good, but did you try it, and can you get the latest time?

Comment: `alias curdate='date +%H:%M:%S'` would do the same thing; no need for the `echo`.